# Codeigniter and data from ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I've been playing with this for a while and not able to get it to work. I am using CodeIgniter and on click of button `$('.galName').click(initUpdate);` I am calling function:

```
function initUpdate()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    //grab id from link update_xxxx

    //get gallery information
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/update',
        data: id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json)
        {
            alert(json);
        }
    });
}
```

I can alert the id after var is set and that's correct. Here is the function called within CodeIgniter controller.

```
public function update()
        {
            $id = $this->input->post('id');

            echo json_encode($id);
        }
```

If I set `$id="something"` and `alert(json)` it works fine and alerts whatever I set something to. However, my issue is with `$id = $this->input->post('id');` It's not pulling my data from the ajax request. This must be the incorrect way of doing within CodeIgniter and I haven't been able to track down the solution otherwise. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there's not POST request, so $id is FALSE and json_encode, therefore, too. Try var_dumping $this->input->post('id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set the key part of the key/value pair, try

```
function initUpdate()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    //grab id from link update_xxxx

    //get gallery information
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/update',
        data: {"id": id},// set the "id" key
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json)
        {
            alert(json);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, silly mistake, been staring at that one too long!!